# InvocationException: Program terminated with status: 3221225477

Tags: graphviz, pydot

I'm trying to visualize a decision tree using pydotplus. Below is the code snippet.

```
if image_file_name is not None:

    dot_data = export_graphviz(decision_tree_model, feature_names=features,out_file=None,filled=True,rounded=True)

    graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)

    colors = ('turquoise', 'orange')

    edges = collections.defaultdict(list)

    for edge in graph.get_edge_list():

         edges[edge.get_source()].append(int(edge.get_destination()))

    for edge in edges:

        edges[edge].sort()    

        for i in range(2):

            dest = graph.get_node(str(edges[edge][i]))[0]

            dest.set_fillcolor(colors[i])

    graph.write_png(image_file_name)
```

Whenever the last statement gets executed, I get this message.

Troubleshooting Steps Performed by me:

1. Uninstalled both Anaconda and Python.
2. Made a fresh installation of Python and Anaconda.
3. Installed Graphviz and Pydotplus and added the path of Graphviz directory to system path.
4. Started the Jupyter notebook terminal and tried executing the code. But still this issue is not yet fixed.

Python Version used: 3.7.1

Anaconda version used: Anaconda3-5.3.1

Can anyone please assist me from here?